# Show error message if required no.of numbers are not given - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

Hi i'm new to angularjs development and i'm struggling with form validations.

I have a input field that allows maximum of 8 digits. I want to show a error message if 8 digits are NOT given. Also the error message should disapear when 8 digits are given.

How can i do this?

**My field**

```
<input   maxlength="8" ng-model="customer.customerId" class="form-control" id="id_customer_select_id" placeholder="Enter existing customer id" ng-change="selectCustomer()" name="customer_id" ng-value="customerId" required="required" >
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `ng-maxlength` and `ng-minlength`.

Comment: i tried ng-maxlength but it did not work. Only maxlength worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> It would a better option to use `<form> </form>` for the validation
>
> also use `ng-messages` to display your validation error message
>
> Given below is the example how to use validation for your question:

**Demo Example**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Number" name="number" ng-model="mobile" ng-maxlength="8" required />
  <div ng-messages="formName.number.$error" item- style="color: red">
    <div ng-message="required">Max number entered!! </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div ng-show="formName.elementName.$invalid && formName.elementName.$dirty">
    <span  ng-show="formName.elementName.$error.required">
        <div style="font: normal 20px courier">This field should be 8 numbers long</div>
    </span>
</div>
```